# Orchard MediaPickerField to MediaLibraryPickerField

Tags: orchardcms

I am currently trying to update a site from Orchard 1.6 to 1.8.
Ran into some issues at the Media -> Media Library step.

We have this in our Migrations.cs

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(typeof(CarouselRecord).Name, table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                .Column<string>("Interval", column => column.WithDefault(""))
                .Column<string>("MinHeight", column => column.WithDefault(""))
            );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            typeof(CarouselPart).Name, cfg => cfg
                .WithField("CarouselImage1", fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaPickerField").WithDisplayName("Img1"))
                .WithField("CarouselImage2", fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaPickerField").WithDisplayName("Img2"))
                .WithField("CarouselImage3", fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaPickerField").WithDisplayName("Img3"))
                .WithField("CarouselImage4", fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaPickerField").WithDisplayName("Img4"))
                .Attachable()
            );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("CarouselWidget", cfg => cfg
                .WithPart(typeof(CarouselPart).Name)
                .WithPart("WidgetPart")
                .WithPart(typeof(CommonPart).Name)
                .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget")
            );
```

After disabling the Media module and Enabling the Media Library Module (and migrating the Media Files and Media picker fields), this stopped working completelty, crashing at this line in the .cshtml:

```
<div class="item"><a href="@Model.ContentPart.CarouselImage2.AlternateText"><img src="@(Href(Model.ContentPart.CarouselImage2.Url))" alt="" /></a></div>
```

First i tried updating the template to use MediaLibraryPickerFields instead, but no luck.
Turns out, when i go to admin -> widgets -> edit widget, the media fields for the widget is gone.

Did i do something wrong in the updating process, or do i have to write new updates in Migrations.cs to remove the MediaPickerFields and add MediaLibraryPickerFields instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Months and no answer, thought i would close this.
What i ended up doing was removing the MediaPickerFields

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            typeof(CarouselPart).Name, cfg => cfg
               .RemoveField("CarouselImage1")
               .RemoveField("CarouselImage2")
               .RemoveField("CarouselImage3")
               .RemoveField("CarouselImage4")
                .Attachable()
            );
```

and then adding a MediaLibraryPickerField instead

```
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
        typeof(CarouselPart).Name, cfg => cfg
            .WithField("CarouselImages", fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField").WithDisplayName("Images").WithSetting("MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.Multiple", "true"))
            .Attachable()
        );
```

Not optimal due to the loss of data, but it was not a big issue in this case.